# Java RMI java.security.AccessControlException: access denied

Tags: java, rmi

I'm writing a client-server program with Java RMI and I'm getting an error:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

My code looks like this:

```
package xxx;

import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class Server extends Engine implements RemoteInterface {

public Server() {
    super();

    if(System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }

    try {
        Naming.rebind("Test", this);

        System.out.println("Bound in registry!");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void test() throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("test() invoked");
}
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgot to add the registry and to implement Serializable. Problem solved. I also removed the SecurityManager.

Comment: You forgot several other things too. Neither of those omissions would cause this problem.

Comment: Well, then you're wrong because adding those fixed the problem.

Comment: The only things that could fix that problem would be removing the SecurityManager or fixing the .policy file.

Comment: That's one besides the two others I mentioned. Edited the post.

Comment: That's the 'one' that fixed the problem, exactly as I said. Adding the Registry and implementing Serializable did not fix it. Nothing wrong with what I said whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed a SecurityManager but you haven't granted yourself enough permissions to execute this code.

Why do you think you need a SecurityManager at all? Unless you are planning to run uploaded code I would just get rid of it